# Как отключить определенные компоненты Bootstrap 4?

Tags: css, bootstrap

Не использую некоторые компоненты Bootstrap 4, такие как модальные окна, кнопки и т. п.
Встал вопрос: как их можно отключить?

Comment: не включая jQuery  используешь только сетку

Comment: @Избытоксусликов причем здесь jQuery и сетка?

Comment: если jQuery не включать то осталные функции типо аккордеона слайдера и т.п. не работают

Comment: на странице загрузки bootstrap имеется возможность выбрать компоненты, которыми вы будете пользоваться, для уменьшения размера файлов css и js

Comment: на странице загрузки bootstrap имеется возможность выбрать компоненты, которыми вы будете пользоваться, для уменьшения размера файлов css и js

Comment: @AuRoom возможно, даже есть ссылка на эту страницу?

Comment: @Избытоксусликов `если jQuery не включать` почему я его не должен включать или выключать? Вопрос к jQuery не имеет вообще никакого отношения...

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/customize/ - вот 3-й, а 4-й изначально в пакете несколько версий css.

Comment: `а 4-й изначально в пакете несколько версий css` если я правильно понимаю, там единственный вариант Bootstrap 4, и нет там никаких версий...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение нашлось на [стороннем ресурсе](https://toster.ru/q/500144):

```
npm i bootstrap@4.0.0-beta.3
```

В bootstrap.scss отключаем ненужные компоненты простым комментированием.